# Password validating

Tags: php, javascript, web

I am trying to validate confirm passwords in PHP using JavaScript by this code:

```
if($_POST['PasswordField']== $_POST['ConfirmPassword'] && $_POST['PasswordField']>='8')
{
    echo "Succed <br>";
}
else
{
    echo "filed <br>";
}
```

It works well with matching the two passwords, but the length of the password is not working.  But if I enter a password which is less than 8 character it succeeds - why is this?

Also, how can I check password strength using JavaScript but not using Regular expressions?

Comment: Why not just test if the password is equal to an already set password?

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript in your post... and what's wrong with regular expressions?

Comment: @ceejayoz: sorry man mistake i mean php  and i want to check the strength of the password using php or javascript i dont wont to use Regular expression i found it easer to work with

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) method to get the length of the string that is contained in $_POST['PasswordField']. And you should not check it with a string '8'. So it needs to be like:

```
<?php
    function isPasswordValid($password1, $password2){
        if(strlen($password1) >= 8)    
           if($password1 == $password2) 
                return true;

        return false;
   }
?>
```

Call this method with the two values from your POST.  Also, use [trim()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to strip whitespaces.
Ohw...and it has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

For password length you need to use `strlen`

```
...&& strlen($_POST['PasswordField']) >= 8)...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_POST['PasswordField']== $_POST['ConfirmPassword'] && strlen($_POST['PasswordField'])>8 && $_POST['PasswordField']>='8')
{
    echo "Succeed <br>";
}
else
{
    echo "failed<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `strlen();` function to get the length of the password.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

```
if (strlen($_POST['PassWordField']) > 8){
//do stuff
}
```